# Image segmentation with Keras and Tensorflow: logits and labels must have the same first dimension when using U-Net architecture

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, image-processing, tensorflow2.0

I'm using this tutorial from the keras website: [Image segmentation with a U-Net-like architecture](https://keras.io/examples/vision/oxford_pets_image_segmentation/). The tutorial runs well, so I want to adapt it for my own use. I have my own data (250x250 images and masks, while the dataset provided is 160x160), categorized in it's own archives. When I try to run it, i get this error:

> Node: 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits'
> logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [2097152,2] and labels shape [2000000]

The architecture is the same as the link provided, I just modified how it search the images (because I have a file structure). So here's what I modified:

```
target_dir = "IA_training_data_final/Toy_mask/"
img_size = (250, 250)
class_list = os.listdir(input_dir)
num_classes = len(class_list)
target_classes = list(range(num_classes))
batch_size = 32
input_img_number = 0
target_img_number = 0
input_img_paths = list()
target_img_paths = list()
val_percent = 0.10

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(input_dir):
    for file in files:
        input_img_number += 1
        input_path = os.path.join(subdir,file)
        input_img_paths.append(input_path)
input_img_paths = sorted(input_img_paths)

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(target_dir):
    for file in files:
        target_img_number += 1
        target_path = os.path.join(subdir,file)
        target_img_paths.append(target_path)
target_img_paths = sorted(target_img_paths)

print("Number of samples:", input_img_number)
print("Number of masks:", target_img_number)
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I did not try the tutorial with your modification, but from a first look you have a mismatch between the format of your labels and what the model expects (logits format is 2D, meaning it outputs a one-hot-encoded format when your labels are 1D). Try using [categorical_crossentropy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/categorical_crossentropy) instead of [sparse_categorical_crossentropy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/sparse_categorical_crossentropy).
Or you can change your label format with [utils.to_categorical](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/to_categorical) and [utils.to_ordinal](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/to_ordinal)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).